# Has anybody here actually endeavored to get an app digitally signed?

Tags: vba, digital-signature

I am absolutely confused now about where to even start.  I have an app that I just found out is getting bounced because its not 'trusted' (due to macros) .

I know how to unblock the Windows "MOTW"  (aka Mark of the Web);  to allow the file to run.  But I cant see explaining this step to hundreds of browsing customers... I need some guidance here.   I need my VBA project to be 'signed' and time stamped.   The info on how to get this done is extremely vague.

Comment: The process how to sign a macro is explained here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/digitally-sign-your-vba-macro-project-956e9cc8-bbf6-4365-8bfa-98505ecd1c01 - I think it's not complicated to understand. However, when a customer is not trusting you (your certificate) or disables macros at all, your code cannot run.

Comment: Thanks; but not really helpful... I've waded through most the microsoft discussions on this... None of them are viable solutions.   Microsoft clearly states that if I don't have a cert  then I need to get one ..(It ends there with an outdated list of CAs).  I dont have the $300.00 plus  to obtain one.    

I did take steps to contact and phone-chat with a  Digicert CA rep; who explained that his products cant support accde files.   
No Matter ... I am scrapping the Office Access project... (What the hell was i thinking?) 
Moving on to Visual Studio; Should have done in the first place.